# singular or plural

Tags: grammar

I read a line of job description on a website:

What you'll do :

> 1. Assist partners on our **product** and service**s** promptly via multiple channel**s**.
> 2. Build firm knowledge on **product**, process**es**, and policies

They use "product" in singular form, this means they only have 1 product. Right?
If they have many products, can I use "product" in singular form to talk about their products generally?

*Another line in that job description:

> 3.Review and identify root cause for all intensified cases to propose **improvements to reduce recurrence.**

I think that If I add "the", the sentence is still correct (...**the** improvements to..). Right?
**"The"** is optional here. Right?

Comment: The sentence isn't talking about _particular_ improvements, but any improvements that the successful candidate may think of, so the definite article is not appropriate.

Comment: Could you please answer my question about the word “product”?

Comment: That's more difficult to answer - I was leaving it to others who may know more about business English. Depending on what kind of firm it is, they may consider that they supply only one 'product'.

Answer (score 1):

> They use "product" in singular form, this means they only have 1
> product. Right?

not necessarily, product can stand for example for art, software, health care, banking, etc.:

- our product is handmade glass
- our product is software
- our product is health care
- our product is investment banking

and most likely with a lot of ramifications and sub-products within the "product", the business category they are in. Which leads to your second point:

---

> can I use "product" in singular form to talk about their products
> generally?

Yes, in this context you can use product to refer to the global business offer they have.

---

> I think that If I add "the", the sentence is still correct

***the*** doesn't sound right here, because adding ***the*** in this context would indicate that those improvements already exist, on contrary to the task asking to  find such improvements.